What web site can I visit from Safari on my iPhone that will drain the battery the fastest?
Sometimes I need to drain the battery to zero. I can search for apps that are designed to do this, but I'd like to do it with a web site instead. What sites are designed to do this?
Barring that, what sites are not designed for this, but still have the effect of draining the battery really fast? The site needs to do the draining without interaction from me.
For example, the game at hexanaut.io drains the battery pretty quickly, but requires me to be playing the game the whole time.

Why do you need to drain the battery and why do it through Safari?

This sounds like an XY Problem   What practical problem are you trying to solve with “draining your battery quickly?”

Don’t do that.
Apple has a handy checklist for you. Do the opposite.

https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

Since Safari is engineered to preserve battery at all costs and the worst way to flatten a battery. Here’s my recommendation.

Turn the brightness to maximum, set the screen to never lock and never dim, disable low power mode
Play streaming music. (Safari is fine here, but apps that never pause are better)
Open maps and navigate to a place.
Then open find my and track anything you have registered.

This should drain things rapidly. If you must have a web site, try a benchmark like https://browserbench.org/Speedometer3.0/
